# Two formulas for $n(A \cup B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying to solve a few problems related to sets using Venn diagrams.Certain questions required me to find $n(A \cup B).

My teacher had given me the formula 
$$
n(A \cup B)=n(\text{only } A)+ n(\text{only } B) + n(A \cap B).
$$

However, I came to find on the internet that the formula it is actually $$
n(A \cup B) = n(A) + n(B) − n(A \cap B).
$$
Is there a negative or a positive sign in front of the $n(A \cap B)$?

Is the formula different when using it in Venn diagrams?

Comment: I think you missed a second, critical difference between the two formulas, in addition to the sign before the last term. So both formulas are correct as written.

Answer (score 1):

Both formulas are correct:
$$
\begin{align*}
n(A \cup B) &= n((A \setminus B) \dot{\cup} (B \setminus A) \dot{\cup} (A \cap B)) \\
&= n(A \setminus B) + n(B \setminus A) + n(A \cap B) \\ 
&= n(A \setminus B) + n(B \setminus A) + 2n(A \cap B) - n(A \cap B) \\
&= (n(A \setminus B) + n(A \cap B)+ (n(B \setminus A) + n(A \cap B)) - n(A \cap B) \\ 
&= n(A) + n(B) - n(A \cap B).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Here "$A \setminus B$" means "$A$ without $B$" which in your case is "$\text{only } A$" and similarly for $B \setminus A$.

Comment: What is the dot atop $\cup$?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor $\cup$ denotes the union and the dot above just emphasizes that this is a disjoint union.